# App Group for Apps with different Developer Accounts

Tags: ios, macos, ios-app-group, appgroups

There are 2 Apps. Both belong to the same organization but have different developer accounts. Both are Mac Apps. Can they still be a part of the same App Group for sharing data, without changing the developer accounts?

Comment: What do mean "the same organisation but different developer accounts"?  Do you mean the same legal entity/company has two different developer accounts?  The apps needs to part of the same developer account to share an app group.

Comment: Yes, I mean the same legal entity/company.

Comment: Ok.  The answer is no then.  The apps need to be published by the same developer account.